# How to upload an image to .ashx url in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, image, upload

I have searched a lot on google as well as on stackoverflow but did not get any satisfactory solution which works for me.

I have to upload an image on some particular url which is ending with extension **.ashx**.
I have seen how to upload on php server but here i am not getting any clue.

Please help me by providing some sample code.

Comment: Do you want to upload it to IIS Server?

Comment: dont think there is any difference if to what backend you uploading if upload method is POST

Comment: Actually i have to upload it on dot net server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding aspx is the page and the .ashx is the code file which response back the output, in string format and [.ashx file is a web handler. A web handler file works just like an aspx file...](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/151908-What-.ashx-page.aspx).

So we consider.ashx same as .aspx then this code should work for you(which is running for me for .aspx page). This is making request to .net server.

**iOS**

```
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation ( img , 90 );

    NSString *urlString =@"www.xyz.com/ImageUpload.aspx?filename=test";

    NSLog(@"IMAGE_UPLOAD_URL -------------> %@",urlString);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[ NSMutableURLRequest alloc ] init ] autorelease ];
    [request setURL :[ NSURL URLWithString :urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod : @"POST" ];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [ NSString stringWithFormat : @"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@" ,boundary];
    [request addValue :contentType forHTTPHeaderField : @"Content-Type" ];
    /*  body of the post */
    NSMutableData *body = [ NSMutableData data ];
    [body appendData :[ NSData dataWithData :imageData]];
    [request setHTTPBody :body];
    NSData *returnData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest :request returningResponse : nil error : nil ];

    NSString *returnString = [[ NSString alloc ] initWithData :returnData encoding : NSUTF8StringEncoding ];
    InfoLog(@"_______  IMAGE_UPLOAD response -------------> .%@.",returnString);
```

**.NET**

Retrieving image like this for .aspx page

```
    if (Request.QueryString["filename"] != null)
    {
        string filename = Request.QueryString["filename"].ToString();
        string saveFilePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CPSBImageFolder"].ToString();
        //string saveFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/images");
        saveFilePath = saveFilePath + filename;
        Stream objStream = Request.InputStream;
        StreamReader objStreamReader = new StreamReader(objStream);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(objStreamReader.BaseStream, true);
        ImageCodecInfo[] info = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        EncoderParameters param = new EncoderParameters(1);
        param.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
        image.Save(saveFilePath, info[1], param);
        Response.Write("true");
    }
```

Not sure but hope this give you a clue.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the variable(NSData) you are using to upload image is not null & your dot net server is receiving request.